# login with facebook using oauth

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
<?php
require "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '3288@@@@@@@@@@',
    'secret' => 'ca2@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

I have made the app in the graph api  and I have very little knowledge of graph api . I want to make a facebook login page in which user clicked on it and my app will generate the oauth for the user . after that i need the USERNAME, EMAIL,BIRTHDAY,NAME   in the fre filled forms

I'm searching for this code from 3 night, but i didn't  find the solution! If you have a suggestion, please write to me it! Please, anyway thanks and good day :)

Comment: You could emulate the logging in POST request, it's pretty easy.

Comment: @user2342080 I am working on this for the 1st time , could u explain me with example ...............

Comment: @user2342080 please rply

Comment: In the developers site, search for the login code. Its quite simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use POST request to simulate login. I don't know Facebook's inputs, so you need to look closely into it's HTML, but here is a code for a simple PHP cURL request.

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Facebook Login',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'myfbpass'
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

[image: Facebook]

Of course, Facebook has automatic login detection by using those hidden fields for getting the sessions, but using DOM Document, you can easily get those values and emulate it, at least thats how I was able to simulate login for http://z8games.com/

Good luck

**Code Credit:**
http://codular.com/curl-with-php

**Edit:**
If you are lazy, you can go ahead and try this page - http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/290893/facebook-login-with-curl

Answer (score 0):

[Temboo](http://www.temboo.com) makes it simple to implement Facebook OAuth by breaking the process down into two steps:

- `ÌnitializeOAuth` returns the Facebook authorization URL that you need to show your users so that they can grant your app access to their Facebook accounts.
- `FinalizeOAuth` returns the access token you need to programmatically read/write a user's Facebook data.

What's more, you can test these calls from your browser and generate the source code you need in the language of your choice.

Here's a [short video](https://www.temboo.com/videos#oauthchoreos) that shows you how to do this with Temboo, and you can check out an example and source code [here](https://www.temboo.com/examples).

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions!)

Comment: please can you explain me because i am using this facebook api for the  first time

Comment: I recommend that you start with the Facebook login demo on this page - https://www.temboo.com/examples Once you have that up and running it should be should be pretty straightforward to get other information like birthday etc.