# CURL, Send Login request useing curl

Tags: php, html, http, curl, web-deployment

so i have this basic html fourm

```
<form action="action.php" class="btn" autocomplete="on">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" /><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" /><br />
  <div align="center">
    <p><input type="submit"  value="Local" /></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

and in my action.php i have

```
$ch = curl_init();
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$postData = array(
        'login' => '$username',
        'pwd' => '$password'
    );

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'facebook.com',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
```

My question is when i hit the submit button it opens up facebook.com but does not do anything. all i really want is a true or false if login was successful. is there a way to just find out if the given username and password are correct? and i know this is basic but i am new to php sorry :-p

Comment: try adding form tag attribute method="post"

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `method='POST'` on your `<form>` as an attribute.

Like this...

```
<form action="action.php" method='POST' class="btn" autocomplete="on">
```

---

### Why no response ?

You need to add this cURL parameter `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false`.

Such that .. your code looks like

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'facebook.com',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false  //<---- See I added it here
));
```

Comment: thank you for the response but i did and still a no go

Comment: sorry but it still does not seem to work. does it matter what the name, or variable name of the password and username are. for example how does it know when it transfers the information what the username is and what the password is? on facebook the password html element has name="pass" but mine is name="password", does that even matter?

Comment: Yes that matters ! The `$postData` should match with the facebook `<form>` fields.

Comment: ok so it was that i think and apparently there are hidden inputs fields that you need to post. they hide random data in the html -.-. but now do you know of a way for it to just return true or false and not direct you to the page?

Comment: Why not make use of **OAuth** instead ? See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333056/login-with-facebook-using-oauth)

Comment: well i was just using FB to test to see if it was my schools site not working with it. its part of a project. i need to make a simple login and bounce it off my school's login page to see if it is a valid username and password. all i can get it to do it go to the login page it just does nothing when its there. i dont even want it to go there i just want a true or false response.

Comment: but thanks for that link ill read http://codular.com/curl-with-php like crazy to try and figure it out :-D